# How do you say an IP address?

Tags: programming

I know how to say numbers in English, but I wonder if IP addresses are said in some special way. For instance, 127.0.0.1: I would say "one hundred twenty seven dot zero dot zero dot one". Is it correct or does it sound awkward? Should the tokens be said digit by digit? Should the zeros be said "o" instead of "zero" (as in telephone numbers)?

Comment: Umm, i want to know this too. And i think the zeros should be said "zero" not "o".

Comment: In this specific instance I typically say, one twenty seven zero zero one or just *localhost* or *the loopback address* whichever makes sense in context. In general I never say "hundred" and I skip saying *dot* whenever it is unambiguous- I.e., I would say one ninety two one sixty eight but I would say thirty dot seven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying "one hundred twenty seven dot zero dot zero dot one" is a bit awkward, in my experience.  I've never heard an IP address expressed in terms of "hundreds".  Generally, you hear an IP address stated as one of two ways:

Each octet digit by digit:

> one two seven dot zero dot zero dot one

Each octet in a group, with pauses for dots:

> one two seven, zero, zero, one

Of course, there are variations on this.  Sometimes, you hear the octet expressed as a single number, like "one twenty seven", or "two fifty five", but never "one hundred twenty seven" or "two hundred fifty five".

I've heard people use "oh" for "zero", but that sounds weird to me, unless it's a middle digit, like:  "two oh eight" and "one oh nine", but never "one twenty seven dot oh dot..."

Comment: And FYI, I don't have a hard source, other than a decade worth of experience in IT and networking.

Comment: Well,I'm glad to have asked this question because in my language (Catalan) we use to say IP addresses with hundreds. Perhaps because saying hundreds is 1 syllabe shorter than in English (200 = dos-cents vs two-hun-dred) :D. Thank you!